# Qual é o valor padrão para o atributo "resize" em um textarea?

Tags: html, textarea

Como deixar uma `textarea` ajustável depois que foi definido "resize: none"?

Por exemplo, tenho uma `textarea` que tem um valor definido como `resize:none` no CSS, porém quero deixar o valor padrão colocando um trecho inline.

```css
.my_textarea{
   border: 2px solid pink;
   resize: none;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

Qual é o valor padrão para o atributo "resize" em um textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O valor padrão é: `auto`.

```
resize: auto;
```

Como sabemos disso ? Podemos ver no **user agent stylesheet** do navegador.

```
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    flex-direction: column;
    resize: auto; /* Aqui */
    cursor: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra maneira de fazer isso é usando o valor `both`.

Veja:

```css
.my_textarea{
   border: 2px solid pink;
   resize: none;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="my_textarea"></textarea>
<textarea class="my_textarea" style="resize: both"></textarea>
```

Lembrando que esse não é o valor padrão, mas que faz com que se comporte da maneira que geralmente os `textarea` vem configurado por padrão.

De acordo com o [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp):

> **both**: The user can adjust both the height and the width of the element

Answer (score 3):

Segundo o [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea):

> Gecko 2.0 introduced support for resizable textareas. This is
>   controlled by the resize CSS property. Resizing of textareas is
>   enabled by default...

Traduzindo fica:

> O Gecko 2.0 introduziu suporte para textareas redimensionáveis. Isso é
>   controlado pela propriedade CSS de redimensionamento.
>   Redimensionamento de textareas é habilitado por padrão...

Que segundo a [descoberta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/177929/32827) do @DiegoSouza, o valor padrão para habilitado é `auto`.